# How to use scanf in a loop to read data until a EOL?

Tags: c, function, scanf, space, eof

the problem I have is as follows:

I need to create a function in C, using the standard libraries.
This function should read data from standard input as follows: value1 value2 value3

Whose type is uint32_t.

The problem is that I do not like that much data going to enter, I can just finish reading the data when the user enter a line that does not respect the format given, or when entering a line with spaces or when entering an EOF.

I was reading several answers to similar problems in the page and this is the code that I did:

```
int main(void) {
uint32_t value1, value2, value3;
int ret = 3;
char ch;
while (true) {
    printf("Enter the data:\n");
    ret = scanf("%u %u %u", &value1, &value2, &value3);
    if ((ret != 3) || (getc(stdin) == EOF) ||
        (getchar() == ' ')) {
        break;
    }
    printf("\nYou entered: %u, %u, %u\n", value1, value2, value3);
}
printf("Finish..");
return 0;
}
```

But not working properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest:

- read the line using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)
- read the line populated by `fgets()` with `sscanf()`, similar to how `scanf()` is currently used

this has the benefit of reading the line *always*, whereas the posted code needs to discard the line if the `scanf()` fails, on invalid input for example.

Example:

```
printf("Enter the data:\n");
char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
{
    uint32_t values[3];
    if (sscanf(line, "%u %u %u", &values[0], &values[1], &values[2]))
    {
        printf("\nYou entered: %u, %u, %u\n", values[0], values[1], value[2]);
        break;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input, retry...\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had to modify a bit to get what I really was looking for, but your idea was good.